# Do I need to use MetaTag http-equiv with DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN?

Tags: asp.net, html, w3c

I use Asp.net
In my document I use:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
```

I would like to know if is necessary to add also this MetaTag:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
```

Thanks for your tme on this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You *should* add the meta tag, though it is not compulsory.

The `DOCTYPE` doesn't not automatically tell you what the character set is, so you should add the information that the file is encoded as `UTF-8`.

You should also ensure the `content-type` HTTP header is also set to `UTF-8`.

Answer (score 1):

**Doctype Definition**

> The doctype declaration should be the very first thing in an HTML document, 
>   before the `<html>` tag.
>
> The doctype declaration is not an HTML tag; it is an instruction to the web 
>   browser about what version of the markup language the page is written in.
>
> The doctype declaration refers to a Document Type Definition (DTD). The DTD 
>   specifies the rules for the markup language, so that the browsers render the 
>   content correctly.

See the reference:

http://www.w3.org/QA/Tips/Doctype

http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/struct/global.html

**Character Encoding**

> The document character set for XML and HTML 4.0 is Unicode (aka ISO 10646). 
>   This means that HTML browsers and XML processors should behave as if they 
>   used Unicode internally. But it doesn't mean that documents have to be 
>   transmitted in Unicode. As long as client and server agree on the encoding, 
>   they can use any encoding that can be converted to Unicode. Read more about 
>   the document character set.
>
> It is very important that the character encoding of any XML or (X)HTML document 
>   is clearly labeled, so that clients can easily map these encodings to Unicode. 
>   This can be done in the following ways...

See The Reference http://www.w3.org/International/O-charset

Both are necessary, but not dependent to each other.

Comment: I have added the w3 org reference as well.

Answer (score 0):

Yes this is perfectly fine to add that just make sure the file extension has .aspx or whatever attached to it.

Example ASP page with html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" /> 
<body bgcolor="black">
<center>
<h2>Hello There!</h2>
<p><%Response.Write(now())%></p>
</center>
</body>
</html>
```

Hope this helps.